# "Unable to bind localhost:8000" error while running sample application in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have just installed GAE launcher and am trying to run a sample application to make sure it works and I am getting the below error.

```
raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8000
2014-03-24 10:54:54 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I am trying to run the python version of the app with python 2.7 and am using windows 8.1 operating system. I did not create any files for the app, I just created a new application and am trying to run it in localhost.

Can someone please tell me what this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another process is already bound to port 8000.  Use `netstat -an` or `netstat -anb` or similar to investigate.  It may be another instance of your development server.

**Edit**: If port 8000 is really occupied, [Command-line arguments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Command-line_arguments) in the [The Python Development Server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) says you can append --admin_port to change the 8000 to another free port.

Comment: I tried the command you said and I am not able to find any applications running `127.0.0.1:8000`. Can you please tell me what I need to look for?

Comment: Hmm, that usually does find other processes.  To be completely sure nothing else is running, try closing all applications, restarting Windows, running a command prompt as Administrator and starting your launcher in that.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that and have changed the port and it works now.

Answer (score 8):

The app server starts two servers: one for your application, the other for development console.

Change the ip address for the development console with:

`dev_appserver.py --admin_port=9000`

Answer (score 5):

For me, I have to use both --admin-port and --port

```
dev_appserver.py --admin_port=9000 --port=9999 app.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it might help others using PyCharm to understand where to set the admin port to something different than 8000.

Go to your "Run/Debug configurations" and in the configuration tab, add the following into "additional options":

```
--admin_port=9000
```

[image: PyCharm Run/Debug Configuration]